# Dynamic test set up/ tear down in Robot Framework?

Tags: automated-tests, integration-testing, robotframework

Our team is transitioning to Robot Framework and we have some conceptual questions. Our biggest at the moment is how to set up a database insert/ delete dynamically, depending on the test we are trying to run. For example, we may have a test suite where we want to test an endpoint like so:

- Record exists, endpoint is valid
- Record exists with data flaw, error is handled correctly
- Record does not exist, error is handled correctly
- ...etc

Each of these requires a different kind of document to be inserted into our database, then deleted, in set up/ tear down.

Currently, we're setting up each test as a separate suite and explicitly setting the insert statements (in this case, the JSON, since we're using MongoDB) in each Suite Setup keyword. We have some factory-method resources to help reduce redundancy but it's still **very** redundant. We are copying and pasting entire .robot files and changing a value or two in each one.

We have tried the `data-driver` library but we haven't been able to get it working with the variable scoping. And we can't set these set up/ tear down steps as simple test steps since we need to be *sure* that each document is created/ destroyed before and after each test.

Comment: without code it would be difficult to understand what is required and what is happening

Comment: I am asking if it is possible to create code that can achieve what I am asking in my question. I have not been able to come up with a concept to even attempt to write code for this.

Comment: Do you want to run the same test case against three (or more) different test setups/suite setups?

Comment: Yes, but very slightly different set ups. For example, we may be inserting a document to a MongoDB collection with 30 different fields, but only want to change the value of one field per test set up.